# is it possible to use tapply without reordering the dataframe

Tags: r, apply, tapply

I have some data that is not ordered for a particular variable (IDS in example). I'd like to be able to use that variable to group the data and get values for proportions of each value in the column contributes to the total for their group. However, when using tapply it reorders the data so that it fits the order of IDS, but is then incorrect for the rest of the df.

Example data and code:

```
id_df <- data.frame(IDS = c(2,1,2,1), data = sample(1:4,4,replace = T))
id_df$portions <- unlist(tapply(id_df$data, id_df$IDS, function(x) x / sum(x)))
```

What I get:

```
  IDS data  portions
1   2    1 0.6666667
2   1    4 0.3333333
3   2    1 0.5000000
4   1    2 0.5000000
```

What I want:

```
  IDS data  portions
1   2    1 0.5000000
2   1    4 0.6666667
3   2    1 0.5000000
4   1    2 0.3333333
```

Comment: `ave(id_df$data, id_df$IDS, FUN = function(x) x/sum(x))`

Comment: Or `id_df %>% 
    group_by(IDS) %>% 
    mutate(portions = data/sum(data))`

Comment: or setDT(id_df)[,portions := data/sum(data), by = IDS]

Comment: As pointd out earlier you need `ave` function instead of `tapply`